# ¿Por qué SqlServer me guarda un iD int Identity como registro número 100-algo, cuando el anterior es 7 ? - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Tengo una tabla Productos en una base de datos, con los siguientes campos:

**Id int Identity Primary Key**

**Codigo int Not Null**

**Nombre varchar(100) Not Null**

**Precio float Not Null**

**Cantidad int Not Null**

**Fk_Codigo int Foreign Key References Factura(Codigo);**

"manualmente"(Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) inserté 7 registros:

**INSERT INTO Producto(Codigo, Nombre, Precio, Cantidad, Fk_Codigo) VALUES(10,'Televisor',9000,2,1);**

**INSERT INTO Producto(Codigo, Nombre, Precio, Cantidad, Fk_Codigo) VALUES(11,'Laptop DELL',15000,3,1);**

**INSERT INTO Producto(Codigo, Nombre, Precio, Cantidad, Fk_Codigo) VALUES(12,'Refrigeradora',20000,4,1);**
... etc.

y el iD identity colocó bien los valores de 1 al 7 pero en mi aplicación con Windows Forms, cuando hago la inserción de nuevos productos, el iD identity comienza a enumerar a partir del número 1,000.

de esta manera hago la conexión:

```
  public void ProductInsert(int ProductCode, string ProductName, float ProductPrice, int ProductCant, int ProductFk)
  {
     SqlCommand command;
     string query = "INSERT INTO Producto(Codigo, Nombre, Precio, Cantidad, Fk_Codigo) VALUES(" + ProductCode + ", '" + ProductName + "', " + ProductPrice + ", " + ProductCant + ", " + ProductFk + ")";

      try
      {
         connection.Open();
         command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      catch(SqlException e)
      {
         MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
      }
      finally
      {
        connection.Close();
      }
  }
```

Inserta todo bien, excepto el iD, debería de insertar 8 pero en cambio lo hace a partir de 1,000.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te esta faltando identity (1,1)

Comment: las propiedades del campo id en el management studio dice que ya lo tienen. aunque intentaré hacer el alter table para agregarlo.

Comment: si quieres poner el comentario como respuesta y lo marco, me funcionó. tuve que escribir toda la db de cero, me llevó mi rato.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-hacer la base de datos es tentador, y está bien para proyectos de práctica, pero qué harías si eso ocurre en el servidor de producción? Detendrías todas las operaciones para hacer un drop database y restaurar un backup sólo por un salto de mil números? Qué tan reciente es el backup? Está corrupto?

Nuestro cerebro ve el salto y piensa que algo anda mal, pero en realidad, para los motores de bases de datos es **totalmente indistinto**.

Por qué digo que no importa?

Porque tu llave primaria no necesariamente debe ser un id autoincrementable. Una llave primaria es aquella que identifica un registro de forma única e inequívoca. En un sistema real de inventario, un abanico no es identificado por su campo identity. El abanico está identificado por su SKU o Número de parte. ESA es la llave primaria de la tabla. Al abanico no le interesa si el registro anterior tiene un identity 19 y el del abanico es 134,934. Tus where y tus join irán en el sku el 95% del tiempo.

Para responder a tu pregunta "Por qué sucede"?

Identity Cache.

El valor del identity column se guarda en una tabla de sistema llamada `sys.identity_columns`. Este valor es agnóstico de la transacción y no le interesa si la transacción está commited o si le dieron rollback, porque no le hace rollback al valor en la tabla de sistema. Ahora, hay una multitud de razones por las cuales el valor puede incrementar, incluyendo transacciones a las que se hace rollback, sin embargo, únicamente nos interesa la siguiente:

Cada tipo de datos en sql server, tiene una cache determinada, para el caso de `int` es 1000 y para `bigint` es 10000

Por razones de rendimiento, sql server genera 1000 enteros y los mantiene en cache para la tabla donde se está realizando el insert. **Por alguna razón, tu servidor local (imagino) falla** haciendo que sql server pierda esos mil identity, y los re-calcula basado en el valor que ya está en la tabla de sistema que mencionaba antes. **Por eso** es que ves un salto de 1000.

Cómo se soluciona?

Si utilizas sql server 2017, la sentencia

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET IDENTITY_CACHE = OFF
GO
```

Le dice al motor que no haga el caché de los identity, para evitar ese caso. La desventaja yace en que el motor de base de datos tendrá que ir a buscar el valor de la columna identity a la tabla de sistema, en lugar de tenerlo en caché.

En qué escenarios es útil?

Si estás haciendo un sistema de facturación, por razones de auditoría las facturas, aún anuladas, deben ir de forma consecutiva **SÍ O SÍ**. En estos casos, puedes desactivar la caché para evitar esos saltos.

Si utilizas una versión anterior a sql server2017, sugiero no depender tanto de la columna identity.

Estos enlaces te darán más información acerca de esto:

https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-to-avoid-an-identity-jump-issue-identity_cache-with-the-help-of-trace-command-t272/

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/01/24/sql-server-identity-jumping-1000-identity_cache/

Saludos

Answer (score 5):

Identity en **ninguna versión** garantiza que los números sean consecutivos independientemente, de que tenga activado No-Cache.

Como te han indicado en otras respuestas y se puede leer en muchos sitios, realizar un alter database puede activar o desactivar la cache, cosa que en otras versiones anteriores también existía pero era configuración del servidor a través del flag 272, para lo cual era necesario reiniciar el motor. Reducirá los saltos, pero perderás rendimiento.

Prueba realizada en un SQL Server 2019

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SALTOS 
(   
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    VALOR VARCHAR(1)
);
GO
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET IDENTITY_CACHE = OFF
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.SALTOS (VALOR)
VALUES('A')
GO
BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO dbo.SALTOS (VALOR)
    VALUES ('B');

ROLLBACK TRAN;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.SALTOS (VALOR)
VALUES('B')
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.SALTOS;
```

[image: Resultado]

[Identity verdades y mentiras](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/27/identity-o-autonumerico-verdades-y-mentiras/)

Existen varias maneras de crear un id Incremental sin saltos, pero todas requieren de algo más que activar una propiedad.

[Id Incremental. ¿Cómo?](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/23/id-incremental-como/)

Comment: Creo que la primera oración resume lo más importante de todo este asunto. La consecutividad no está garantizada. No dependamos de ella