# Salto no deseado en campo autoincremental SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi base de datos realiza saltos de 1000 en el campo numeroPartida, como pueden ver en la imagen, he buscado informacion y no me sale nada de como solucionarlo

Comment: No es algo que tengas que solucionar. Las bases de datos hacen ese tipo de cosas en los campos autoincrementales porque toman los numeros por lote y no necesariamente respetan la incrementalidad.. .. Solo aseguran que no se repitan y vayan creciendo.. Si estas usando ese numero para otra cosa que no sea un id, entonces no deberias usar un autoincremental....

Comment: A lo que me temo con estos saltos es que como es un INT, que con estos saltos de 1000 se me agoten los registros, porque en verdad si es necesario el autoincrement

Comment: vas a tener mas de 2,147,483,647 registros?

Comment: Obviamente no jajaja es bueno saber la cantidad de registros porque la perosna si registrara muchos numeroPartida pero no tantos asi jajaja, Muchas gracias

Comment: Sql Server no garantiza la unicidad ni la consecutividad de la columna de la tabla que tenga una propiedad `Identity`. (Propiedad identity)[https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15]. Puedes ver más en este hilo (Porque sql me guarda registro numero 100)[https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/416728/por-qu%c3%a9-sqlserver-me-guarda-un-id-int-identity-como-registro-n%c3%bamero-100-algo-c/416766#416766]